# Elasticsearch doesn't respond after index recovering

Tags: elasticsearch

ES not responded to any requests after loosing an index (for unknown reason). After server restart ES trying to recover index but as soon as it read entire index (about 200mb only) ES stop to respond. The last error I saw was `SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query_fetch], all shards failed]`.  I'm using ES on single node virtual server. Index has only one shard with about 3mln documents (200mb).

How I can recover this index?

Here's the ES log

```
[2014-06-21 18:43:15,337][WARN ][bootstrap                ] jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
[2014-06-21 18:43:15,554][WARN ][common.jna               ] Unknown mlockall error 0
[2014-06-21 18:43:15,759][INFO ][node                     ] [Crimson Cowl] version[1.1.0], pid[1031], build[2181e11/2014-03-25T15:59:51Z]
[2014-06-21 18:43:15,759][INFO ][node                     ] [Crimson Cowl] initializing ...
[2014-06-21 18:43:15,881][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Crimson Cowl] loaded [], sites [head]
[2014-06-21 18:43:21,957][INFO ][node                     ] [Crimson Cowl] initialized
[2014-06-21 18:43:21,958][INFO ][node                     ] [Crimson Cowl] starting ...
[2014-06-21 18:43:22,275][INFO ][transport                ] [Crimson Cowl] bound_address {inet[/10.0.0.13:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.13:9300]}
[2014-06-21 18:43:25,385][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Crimson Cowl] new_master [Crimson Cowl][UJNl8hGgRzeFo-DQ3vk2nA][esubuntu][inet[/10.0.0.13:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-06-21 18:43:25,438][INFO ][discovery                ] [Crimson Cowl] elasticsearch/UJNl8hGgRzeFo-DQ3vk2nA
[2014-06-21 18:43:25,476][INFO ][http                     ] [Crimson Cowl] bound_address {inet[/10.0.0.13:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.13:9200]}
[2014-06-21 18:43:26,348][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Crimson Cowl] recovered [2] indices into cluster_state
[2014-06-21 18:43:26,349][INFO ][node                     ] [Crimson Cowl] started
```

After deleting another index on the same node ES respond to request, but failed to recover index. Here's the log

```
[2014-06-22 08:00:06,651][WARN ][bootstrap                ] jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
[2014-06-22 08:00:06,699][WARN ][common.jna               ] Unknown mlockall error 0
[2014-06-22 08:00:06,774][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] version[1.1.0], pid[2035], build[2181e11/2014-03-25T15:59:51Z]
[2014-06-22 08:00:06,774][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] initializing ...
[2014-06-22 08:00:06,779][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Baron Macabre] loaded [], sites [head]
[2014-06-22 08:00:08,766][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] initialized
[2014-06-22 08:00:08,767][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] starting ...
[2014-06-22 08:00:08,824][INFO ][transport                ] [Baron Macabre] bound_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9300]}
[2014-06-22 08:00:11,890][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Baron Macabre] new_master [Baron Macabre][eWDP4ZSXSGuASJLJ2an1nQ][esubuntu][inet[/10.0.0.3:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-06-22 08:00:11,975][INFO ][discovery                ] [Baron Macabre] elasticsearch/eWDP4ZSXSGuASJLJ2an1nQ
[2014-06-22 08:00:12,000][INFO ][http                     ] [Baron Macabre] bound_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9200]}
[2014-06-22 08:00:12,645][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Baron Macabre] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2014-06-22 08:00:12,647][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] started
[2014-06-22 08:05:01,284][WARN ][index.engine.internal    ] [Baron Macabre] [wordstat][0] failed engine
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ParallelPostingsArray.<init>(ParallelPostingsArray.java:35)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.<init>(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:254)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.newInstance(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:279)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ParallelPostingsArray.grow(ParallelPostingsArray.java:48)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField$PostingsBytesStartArray.grow(TermsHashPerField.java:307)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:324)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField.add(TermsHashPerField.java:185)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:171)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.processDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:248)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:253)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:453)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1529)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.innerIndex(InternalEngine.java:532)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:470)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.performRecoveryOperation(InternalIndexShard.java:744)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:228)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:197)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-06-22 08:05:02,168][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Baron Macabre] [wordstat][0] sending failed shard for [wordstat][0], node[eWDP4ZSXSGuASJLJ2an1nQ], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [LC3LMLxgS3CkkG_pvfTeSg], reason [engine failure, message [OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]]]
[2014-06-22 08:05:02,169][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Baron Macabre] [wordstat][0] received shard failed for [wordstat][0], node[eWDP4ZSXSGuASJLJ2an1nQ], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [LC3LMLxgS3CkkG_pvfTeSg], reason [engine failure, message [OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]]]
[2014-06-22 08:53:22,253][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] stopping ...
[2014-06-22 08:53:22,267][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] stopped
[2014-06-22 08:53:22,267][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] closing ...
[2014-06-22 08:53:22,272][INFO ][node                     ] [Baron Macabre] closed
[2014-06-22 08:53:23,667][WARN ][bootstrap                ] jvm uses the client vm, make sure to run `java` with the server vm for best performance by adding `-server` to the command line
[2014-06-22 08:53:23,708][WARN ][common.jna               ] Unknown mlockall error 0
[2014-06-22 08:53:23,777][INFO ][node                     ] [Living Totem] version[1.1.0], pid[2137], build[2181e11/2014-03-25T15:59:51Z]
[2014-06-22 08:53:23,777][INFO ][node                     ] [Living Totem] initializing ...
[2014-06-22 08:53:23,781][INFO ][plugins                  ] [Living Totem] loaded [], sites [head]
[2014-06-22 08:53:25,828][INFO ][node                     ] [Living Totem] initialized
[2014-06-22 08:53:25,828][INFO ][node                     ] [Living Totem] starting ...
[2014-06-22 08:53:25,885][INFO ][transport                ] [Living Totem] bound_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9300]}
[2014-06-22 08:53:28,913][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [Living Totem] new_master [Living Totem][D-eoRm7fSrCU_dTw_NQipA][esubuntu][inet[/10.0.0.3:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-06-22 08:53:28,939][INFO ][discovery                ] [Living Totem] elasticsearch/D-eoRm7fSrCU_dTw_NQipA
[2014-06-22 08:53:28,964][INFO ][http                     ] [Living Totem] bound_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.0.0.3:9200]}
[2014-06-22 08:53:29,433][INFO ][gateway                  ] [Living Totem] recovered [1] indices into cluster_state
[2014-06-22 08:53:29,433][INFO ][node                     ] [Living Totem] started
[2014-06-22 08:58:05,268][WARN ][index.engine.internal    ] [Living Totem] [wordstat][0] failed engine
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.<init>(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:261)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField$FreqProxPostingsArray.newInstance(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:279)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.ParallelPostingsArray.grow(ParallelPostingsArray.java:48)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField$PostingsBytesStartArray.grow(TermsHashPerField.java:307)
        at org.apache.lucene.util.BytesRefHash.add(BytesRefHash.java:324)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField.add(TermsHashPerField.java:185)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverterPerField.processFields(DocInverterPerField.java:171)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.processDocument(DocFieldProcessor.java:248)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:253)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:453)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1529)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1199)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.innerIndex(InternalEngine.java:523)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.engine.internal.InternalEngine.index(InternalEngine.java:470)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.performRecoveryOperation(InternalIndexShard.java:744)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.local.LocalIndexShardGateway.recover(LocalIndexShardGateway.java:228)
        at org.elasticsearch.index.gateway.IndexShardGatewayService$1.run(IndexShardGatewayService.java:197)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[2014-06-22 08:58:06,046][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Living Totem] [wordstat][0] sending failed shard for [wordstat][0], node[D-eoRm7fSrCU_dTw_NQipA], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [LC3LMLxgS3CkkG_pvfTeSg], reason [engine failure, message [OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]]]
[2014-06-22 08:58:06,047][WARN ][cluster.action.shard     ] [Living Totem] [wordstat][0] received shard failed for [wordstat][0], node[D-eoRm7fSrCU_dTw_NQipA], [P], s[INITIALIZING], indexUUID [LC3LMLxgS3CkkG_pvfTeSg], reason [engine failure, message [OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]]]
```

Comment: seems like problems with memory heap, but i don't know what exactly to change in ES settings.

Comment: are you using an admin-ui like elasticsearch-head to visualize your cluster?

Comment: how much memory does your instance/server have? what operating system are you running?

Comment: @eliasah yes, I use ES-Head for UI. And now it show that index is unassigned.

Comment: @JohnPetrone my VPS running Ubuntu 12.04 and has 1.6gig of RAM but as far as I remember ES is limited to use only 526mb in config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to recover you're Elasticsearch cluster you will need to allocate more memory to the heap. As you are running on a fairly small instance this may be a bit challenging but here is what you will need to do:

1. Change the configuration to allocate more memory to the heap. Not
   clear what your current settings are but there are several ways to
   boost this - the easiest is to set the environment variable
   `ES_HEAP_SIZE`. I'd start with 1GB, try that and then boost it in
   small increments as you are already near the limit of what you can
   do    with a 1.6GB memory instance. Alternatively you may make
   changes to    the files used to launch Elasticsearch - depends on
   how you have them    installed, but should be in the bin directory
   underneath the    Elasticsearch home directory. For a linux
   installation the files are    `elasticsearch` and
   `elasticsearch.in.sh`.
2. Move to a larger instance. This would be much easier to recover from
   on a system with more memory - so if the above step does not work,
   you could copy all your files to another larger instance and try the
   above steps again with a larger heap size.

Comment: It's helped. But I wonder is there something else instead of moving to another server and increasing HEAP_SIZE?

Comment: You can try tweaking the cache settings but the problem is you don't have enough memory for the size of index you are managing. See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-fielddata.html and http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-cache.html for cache settings that can be modified.

Comment: Today got error `Query Failed [Failed to execute main query]]; nested: ElasticsearchException[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]; nested: ExecutionError[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space]; nested: OutOfMemoryError[Java heap space]; }`. Heap size allready at maximum. What I can do in this situation?

Comment: `indices.cache.filter.size` and `indices.fielddata.cache.size` were set to 15%

Comment: You can try cutting the size of your caches but at this point you really need to move to a larger server or add servers to your cluster.

Comment: This solution is not really correct. Whatever is causing the bug happily consumes the full Heap Space assigned, even when maxed.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat how do you come to that conclusion as you are not the OP and the OP accepted the answer? ES (or any Java app) requiring more heap to accomplish it's tasks is not a bug, it's the nature of how the JVM works.

Comment: @JohnPetrone I know because I tried this solution and it did not work. I will share the correct solution.

Answer (score -3):

What has happened here is your server has become overloaded. Possibly there is a bad sector. What you need to do is delete your existing indices and re-index them.

On Linux,

- Elasticsearch temporary files are kept in `usr/local/var/elasticsearch/`
- Delete this folder, then repopulate your index